# Overriding operators within nested internal classes

Tags: c#, interface, nested, overriding, access-levels

I need to override the `Equals` operator (and therefore, the `GetHashcode` method) in a nested class whose accessibility is `internal`.

When I try to do this, the compiler complains that I can't override Equals - a `public` member - with a `private` method. But I can't make the override `public`, because the class itself is `internal`, and nested.

How does one do this?  How can I override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` in a class that is not `public` (and in fact, is nested and `internal`)?

Comment: Can you post code what you have tried

Comment: Not easily. I'm hoping this question is general enough to have a general answer, like "you need to create an explicit implementation of the interface of..."

Comment: "But I can't make the override public, because the class itself is internal, and nested" - why? Have you tried?

Comment: Wow. While trying to write sample code, I did try, and it does work!

I'm not sure why it works, though. Ordinarily, you can't have a public member in an internal class, right? You can't have a member whose access level is higher than it's containing class?

At any rate - I'm happy now! I can't answer the question or vote, though, cuz I just created my account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure why it works, though.

This behavior is defined in § 3.5.2 of the C# specification:

> The accessibility domain of a nested member `M` declared in a type `T` within a program `P` is defined as follows (noting that M itself may possibly be a type): [...]
>
> - If the declared accessibility of `M` is `internal`, the accessibility domain of `M` is the intersection of the accessibility domain of `T` with the program text of `P`.

This provision requires that for a class with internal accessibility, type members may be equivalently marked either as public or as internal.

> You can't have a member whose access level is higher than it's containing class?

This is accurate; the same section of the specification states that "the accessibility domain of a member is never more inclusive than the accessibility domain of the type in which the member is declared".  It is important to recognize that although the language allows a member of a type with internal accessibility to be *declared* as public, it will still have internal accessibility (as if it were declared as internal).

In other words, in the below segment, the accessibility of `X` is equivalent in both lines:

```
internal class A {public void X() {}}
internal class A {internal void X() {}}
```